# Is it possible to trace the current PHP function/method?

Tags: php

I have a PHP Class method which contains many conditional statements and it stops/returns if certain conditions are true.

For debugging, I want to know which condition actually made the function to return the control.

```
public function handle_request() {
    if ( ! $this->is_data_writable() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! $this->user_has_permissions() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( 'active' != $this->object->status ) {
        return;
    }

    // do the stuff
}
```

I don't have the control over the function/method that calls it.

Comment: use echo "test"; exit; to trace

Comment: You could use a logger to determine which one got triggered

Comment: _"For debugging"_... use a debugger ~ http://php.net/manual/debugger-about.php

Comment: Not an option. `exit` will stop the whole script.

Comment: hope this help you, you can use `debug_backtrace` function, like this `var_dump(debug_backtrace());`

Comment: @ManzoorWani What's wrong with stopping the whole script? You'd be doing this in a test install, right?

Comment: @ceejayoz that class/method is just one part of the code. Other things still need to continue. I need to enable that check in production as well when a lot of things are going on besides that function.

Comment: _" I need to enable that check in production"_... then use logging as suggested by @DarkBee

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use debugger for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use log handling for it

```
public function handle_request() {
        if ( ! $this->is_data_writable() ) {
            error_log("is_data_writable", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
            return;
        }
        if ( ! $this->user_has_permissions() ) {
            error_log("user_has_permissions", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
            return;
        }
        if ( 'active' != $this->object->status ) {
            error_log("not_active", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
            return;
        }

        // do the stuff
}
```

You can customize error handling with your own error handlers to call this function for you whenever an error or warning or whatever you need to log occurs.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_log.asp

Comment: I think u misunderstood the question. No errors are occuring. But `OP` wants to trace which condition made the function stop the routine

Comment: @DarkBee. . Updated my answer .. I think `OP` can log these conditions. It will give him more insight

Comment: That's one approach that looks to be a potential solution. If there isn't anything better, I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the `debug_print_backspace` function to print the call stack. http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Comment: That will print the details about the script/function that called the current function. I want to know about the current function being inside it or may be  better approach

Answer (score 0):

you could use this approach:
create an array of all steps an use a global variable to track the step:

```
$request_error='';
public function handle_request(){
    $steps=['is_data_writable','user_has_permissions','active'];
    global $request_error;
    foreach($steps as $step){

        if($step!='active'){
            if(! $this->$step()){
                $request_error=$step;
                return;
            }
        }else{
            if($step!=$this->object->status){
                $request_error=$step;
                return;
            }
        }

    }
    //do the stuff
}
```

then you can use `$request_error` as you want.

another approach which is very similar is:
create an array of all steps an use a reference  to track the step but this will alter your method prototype:

```
public function handle_request(&$request_error){
    $steps=['is_data_writable','user_has_permissions','active'];
    foreach($steps as $step){

        if($step!='active'){
            if(! $this->$step()){
                $request_error=$step;
                return;
            }
        }else{
            if($step!=$this->object->status){
                $request_error=$step;
                return;
            }
        }

    }
    //do the stuff
}
```

then you can use the assigned value as you want.You could in this approach specify a default value to your argument to make it
optional
Note that you can avoid array but you will write a little more.